# Как отловить ошибку бросаемую Imap

Tags: php, imap, php8

```
  class PostReader
{      
   public function __construct(protected MailConfigInterface $mailConfig)
    {
        $this->resource = imap_open(
            mailbox: $this->mailConfig->getImapAddress(),
            user: $this->mailConfig->getUserName(),
            password: $this->mailConfig->getPassword()
        ) ?: throw new MailRuntimeException(
            message: "Ошибка подключения к: {$this->mailConfig->getImapAddress()}",
            errorCode: MailRuntimeException::ERROR_CONNECTION,
            imapLastError: imap_last_error()
        );
    }
}
```

При подключении к почте по imap, если я например заведомо задам не верны пароль от почты. Imap выдаст: `imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {imap.yandex.ru:993/imap/ssl}` и `Unknown: Retrying PLAIN authentication after [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] AUTHENTICATE invalid credentials or IMAP is disabled sc=q (errflg=1)`

```
try {
  $postMan = new PostReader($config);   
} catch (Error $e) {
    echo $e;
}
```

Игнорируя выброс моего кастомного исключения + у меня не получается в месте вызова через try \ catch отловить ту ошибку что бросает Imap через Throwable, Error, Exception. Если верить документации imap_open при возникновении ошибки должен вернуть False. Но этого не происходит. Собственно вопрос: как мне отловить ошибку от imap и заменить на свою? Ошибки и исключения от других методов ловит спокойно, проблема именно с imap_open()

Comment: Поскольку вы явно только начинаете использовать imap в проекте, мой совет: воспользуйтесь какой-нибудь другой библиотекой. Расширение imap давно мертво, хоть плашки deprecated и не висит.

Comment: А какую альтернативу можете порекомендовать?

Comment: я перелез на horde_imap_client. Но рекомендовать его сложно из-за недостатков документации.

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю

Answer (score 0):

Все оказалось проще чем я думал. Меня спас один единственны символ "@":

```
 public function __construct(protected MailConfigInterface $mailConfig)
{
    error_reporting(error_level: 1); //  моем случае что бы не светились notice
    
    $this->resource = @imap_open( // @ подавляет ошибки метода
        mailbox: $this->mailConfig->getImapAddress(),
        user: $this->mailConfig->getUserName(),
        password: $this->mailConfig->getPassword()
    ) ?: throw new MailRuntimeException(
        message: "Ошибка подключения к: {$this->mailConfig->getImapAddress()}",
        errorCode: MailRuntimeException::ERROR_CONNECTION,
        imapLastError: imap_last_error()
    );
}
```